# Git server cannot push. Unable to create temporary object directory

Tags: git, nginx, fastcgi, nginx-config

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to come up with my own hosted git server and I am having trouble configuring the git options with HTTPs.

I have installed nginx and fastcgi. And those are the following configurations of the git files

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;

                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default (linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default)

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/privkey.pem;

        root /var/www/html;
        server_name [redacted] www.[redacted];
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/git (same as before, linked)

```
git@localhost:/$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/git 
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/privkey.pem;

    server_name git.[redacted];

    auth_basic "login";
    auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/html/git/.htpasswd";
    location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /git;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $uri;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

And everytime I try to push some commits I get:

```
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To https://git.[redacted]/[repo]
! [remote rejected] main -> main (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to https://git.[redacted]/[repo]
```

The directory where git projects are allocated is owned full by the `git` user (is that maybe the problem)?

- Reenabling many times both services.
- Restructuring the /etc/nginx/sites-available/git and the default.
- Resetting the user(s) for the auth_basic
- Ownership of the folders.
- Changing the branches.

Comment: I am not an expert in these setups using nginx but the basic question from your explanation is: what user is running the git process on the server when you push?

Comment: I finally managed to get it working now! Your comment made me clear to change the permissions of the repo... to git:www-data! Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: Glad to have shown the path :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself:

Make the ownership of the repo to git:www-data. The problem as @eftshift0 pointed out, or at least guided to, was who was running the git process and who has ownership on top of the repo!

Therefore, I changed the ownership to the user:group corresponding.

Thanks!